# How to calculate failure change rate through bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, grafana

I am working on a grafana dashboard to display failure change ratio(i.e to calculate the time taken to restore the app from last failure). Below is the sample table

```
+---+---------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|   |  Process Name | Status   | Deployment started  | Deployment completed  |
+---+---------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| 1 | Mobile app    | Success  | 2023-03-25 13:15:06 | 2023-03-25 13:25:06   |
+---+---------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| 2 | Mobile app    | Success  | 2023-03-25 09:05:06 | 2023-03-25 09:15:06   |
+---+---------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| 3 | Mobile app    | Failed   | 2023-03-25 08:25:06 | 2023-03-25 08:18:06   |
+---+---------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| 4 | Mobile app    | Success  | 2023-03-24 16:25:06 | 2023-03-24 16:35:06   |
+---+---------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

Frome the above table I want to calculate the difference between the deployment completed time of failed record and it's next immediate success record.

As per the table, query has to calculate the difference between row 3 and row 2 and should get the difference as

```
+---+---------------+-------------------------------+
|   |  Process Name | Failure change rate           |
+---+---------------+-------------------------------+
| 1 | Mobile app    | 00hours 57minutes 00 seconds  |
+---+---------------+-------------------------------+
```

Even when there and multiple failures I want to calculate the failure change rate of latest failure.

Like mobile app I will have multiple apps, I would have to calculate the failure change rate of all apps and display them in individual rows.

Can someone help me with bigquery to achieve this.

Comment: What should be the expected output?

Comment: Duration of each deployment for the process is never overlapped ?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider below.

```sql
 SELECT *,
        TIMESTAMP_DIFF(
          LEAD(deployment_completed) OVER w,
          deployment_completed,
          SECOND
        ) AS Failure_Change_Rate
   FROM sample_table
QUALIFY status = 'Failed' AND LEAD(status) OVER w = 'Success'
 WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY process_name ORDER BY deployment_started);
```

**Query results**

[image]

- `Failure_Change_Rate` is in seconds
- Using `JUSTIFY_INTERVAL(MAKE_INTERVAL(second=>Failure_Change_Rate))` will return `0-0 0 0:57:0`

  - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/interval_functions#justify_interval